# List index out of range, But I reset the index (Python)

Tags: python

I've been programming for about 1 week.

I'm writing a simple program to loop through this List and increment the variables by 1 each time.

I get the error: List index out of range.

I believe this is because my index value is too high?
But I am resetting the index value before it goes too high with:

```
        index += 1
        index and 7
```

The logical AND should reset index to 0 once it becomes >= 8, shouldn't it?

In this case I don't understand what is wrong. Please see my code:

```
lookups = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
index = 0
dword_C06748 = 0

count = 0

offset1 = 0
rn_offset = 0


def next_value():
    global lookups, index, count
    while count < 18:
        lookups[index] += 1
        index += 1
        index and 7
        count += 1

next_value()
```

Comment: What do you think `index and 7` does?

Comment: `index = index % 8` seems more logical to me.

Comment: @tcaswell I think it performs a logical AND using the variable 'index' with 7. So when index = 8, it will do 8 AND 7. The answer is 0 and should assign 0 to index.

Comment: also, what are you _trying_ to do with this code?  It is _almost_ valid python, but is _very_ non pythonic

Comment: @tcaswell Sorry, maybe it is because I have spent 3 months learning x86 Assembly. And this is my first time with a HLL.

The problem might be because I'm reverse engineering a C function using Python. So I'm just trying to copy the C, and translate it to Python...

Comment: ah, welcome to HLLs.  They make your life easier ;)  Beware of the joke 'A good {fortran,c} programmer can write {fortran, c} in any language'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` is boolean `AND` in python, use `&` for bit-wise AND:

```
index &= 7  #index = index & 7
```

As integers are immutable, you should re-assign the result back to `index`.

Answer (score 3):

`index and 7` does not reset `index`. It just evaluates to a Boolean which is not saved. So this statement has not effect.

Use `index = index % 8` instead. This ensures index will always be lower than 8.

Or you can use

```
 index = index % len(lookups)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
&
```

rather than

```
and
```

Have a look at this resource: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

And good luck learning :)

Comment: you also need to assign the value, as it is the result just goes off to the ether.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use either:

```
if index >= 8:
    index = 0
```

or

```
index = index % 8
```

or an alternative using the inplace modulo operator

```
index %= 8
```

As it says in the Zen of Python (open a Python window and enter `import this`), readability counts.
These options are much more readable than the corrected version of your code, using a bitwise `and` instead, therefore you should use them instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will replicate the output of your code in a more pythonic way:

```
lookups = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def next_value():
    # xrange returns the value 0, 1, ... 17
    for count in xrange(18):   # or just range if you are using py3
        # the mod makes sure the index is always less than 8
        lookups[count % 8] += 1

next_value()
```

Comment: `range` instead of `xrange` in Python 3.x

Comment: Right, I'm still a 2.7 hold out.